# how to have knockout search multiple keywords as well as live search

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i am desperately trying to have knockout apply a live search to my project. This search needs the ability to differentiate between spaces in the query and use them as separated search queries. For example; if user types "Matrix" it pulls up both DVD and Bluray Matrix movies... But if user types in Matrix DVD nothing appears.

I am trying to make it search everything in the data separated by space in the query.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/neosketo/eLgscy1t/10/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>Movie Search</h1>
<form>
  <input id="search" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search for a user" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

<table data-bind="visible: movies().length > 0">
  <thead><tr><th>Type</th><th>Name</th><th>Media</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: movies">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: type"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: media"></td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var movies = [
  { type: 'action',     name: 'The Matrix',                 media: 'DVD'},
  { type: 'action',     name: 'The Matrix',                 media: 'Bluray'},
  { type: 'fantasy',    name: 'Lord of the Rings',  media: 'DVD'},
  { type: 'fantasy',    name: 'Lord of the Rings',  media: 'Bluray'},
  { type: 'comedy',     name: 'Dumb and Dumber',        media: 'DVD'},
  { type: 'comedy',     name: 'Dumb and Dumber',        media: 'Bluray'}
];

var viewModel = {
  movies: ko.observableArray([]),
  query: ko.observable(''),

  search: function(value) {
    viewModel.movies.removeAll();

    if (value == '') return;

    for (var movie in movies) {
      if (movies[movie].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        viewModel.movies.push(movies[movie]);
      }
    }
  }
};

viewModel.query.subscribe(viewModel.search);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Is this what you mean ? https://jsfiddle.net/eLgscy1t/11/

Comment: very close. i see whats going on there. when typing "matrix dvd" it gives me The Matrix DVD, The Matrix DVD, The Matrix Bluray... when it should some how just return The Matrix DVD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start out by extending your movie objects to include their own collection of search terms. You don't want to recalculate this every time you type a character:

```
var moviesWithSearchString = movies.map(function(movie) {
  var ogKeys = Object.keys(movie);
  return Object.assign({}, movie, {
    _searchProps: ogKeys
      .map(function(key) {
        return movie[key].toLowerCase();
      })
  });
});
```

The `_searchProps` property holds an array of search words. For your first movie: `["action", "the matrix", "dvd"]`

Now, in your `search` method, we need to transform the search query into an array of lowercase words as well:

```
var searchVals = value
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(" ");
```

Then, the fun part begins. We want **every** ([`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)) search word to **appear** ([`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)) in **at least once** ([`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)) of our movie's properties:

```
viewModel.movies(moviesWithSearchString.filter(function(movie) {
  return searchVals.every(function(searchVal) {
    return movie._searchProps.some(function(searchProp) {
      return searchProp.includes(searchVal);
    });
  });
}));
```

The working examples:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dkrct5ko/

stack snippet:

```js
var movies = [{
  type: 'action',
  name: 'The Matrix',
  media: 'DVD'
}, {
  type: 'action',
  name: 'The Matrix',
  media: 'Bluray'
}, {
  type: 'fantasy',
  name: 'Lord of the Rings',
  media: 'DVD'
}, {
  type: 'fantasy',
  name: 'Lord of the Rings',
  media: 'Bluray'
}, {
  type: 'comedy',
  name: 'Dumb and Dumber',
  media: 'DVD'
}, {
  type: 'comedy',
  name: 'Dumb and Dumber',
  media: 'Bluray'
}];

var moviesWithSearchString = movies.map(function(movie) {
  var ogKeys = Object.keys(movie);
  return Object.assign({}, movie, {
    _searchProps: ogKeys
      .map(function(key) {
        return movie[key].toLowerCase();
      })
  });
});

var viewModel = {
  movies: ko.observableArray([]),
  query: ko.observable(''),

  search: function(value) {
    var searchVals = value
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ");

    viewModel.movies(moviesWithSearchString.filter(function(movie) {
      return searchVals.every(function(searchVal) {
        return movie._searchProps.some(function(searchProp) {
          return searchProp.includes(searchVal);
        });
      });
    }));
  }
};

viewModel.query.subscribe(viewModel.search);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
table {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
th,
td {
  padding: .2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h1>Movie Search</h1>
  <form>
    <input id="search" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search for a user" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off" />
  </form>

  <table data-bind="visible: movies().length > 0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Media</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: movies">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: type"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: media"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note that some of the `Array` and `String` methods are not supported in old browsers. Check out the linked articles for polyfills.

Comment: Brilliant approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the query term by space and then use the `.some` array method to search through the movies.

```
search: function(value) {
  viewModel.movies.removeAll();

  if (!value) return;

  var values = value.split(' ');

  for (var movie in movies) {
    var found = values.some(function(word) {
        return !!word && movies[movie].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });
    if (found) {
      viewModel.movies.push(movies[movie]);
    }
  }
}
```

`!!word` simply short circuits the search in case the user entered multiple spaces resulting in an empty string from the split.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eLgscy1t/12/

Comment: hmmm... i see. But that makes both dvd and bluray appear when i type the "matrix". and nothing appears when i type "dvd"...